# Components appear only when mouse hovers over them

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I created a `JFrame` with the Swing framework, in which I added a `JButton` that will display a form created on a `JPanel` on the frame.

I added the action listener on the button and it is displaying panel as I expected;

But the boxes of components like radio buttons and checkboxes cannot be seen.

They appear only when I hover mouse over them.

Look at the other option in radio button and checkboxes:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
package codes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JFrameBackground extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
    JTextField t1;
    JButton b1;
    JRadioButton r1;
    JComboBox com1;
    JCheckBox chk1;
    
    JPanel p2;
    JButton b;
    
    

    public JFrameBackground() 
    {
        
        p2=new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(null);
        p2.setBounds(250, 0, 400, 400);
        add(p2);
        
        
        l1 = new JLabel("Name:");
        l1.setBounds(100,10,70,30);
        p2.add(l1);
        
        t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(100,50,70,30);
        p2.add(t1);
        
        l2 = new JLabel("Gender:");
        l2.setBounds(100,130,70,30);
        p2.add(l2);
        
        r1 = new JRadioButton("Male");
        r1.setBounds(100,150,70,30);
        p2.add(r1);
        
        r1 = new JRadioButton("Female");
        r1.setBounds(150,150,70,30);
        p2.add(r1);
        
        l3 = new JLabel("Course:");
        l3.setBounds(100,180,70,30);
        p2.add(l3);
        
        chk1= new JCheckBox("Bca");
        chk1.setBounds(100, 200, 70, 30);
        p2.add(chk1);
        
        chk1= new JCheckBox("BBA");
        chk1.setBounds(150, 200, 70, 30);
        p2.add(chk1);
        
        chk1= new JCheckBox("BCOM");
        chk1.setBounds(200, 200, 70, 30);
        p2.add(chk1);
        
        l4 = new JLabel("Country:");
        l4.setBounds(100,220,70,30);
        p2.add(l4);
        
        String name[] = {"India","USA","UK","Rus"};
        
        com1=new JComboBox(name);
        com1.setBounds(100, 250, 70, 30);
        p2.add(com1);
        
        b1= new JButton("Submit");
        b1.setBounds(140, 300, 90, 30);
        p2.add(b1);
        
        
        
        
        b =new JButton("Show form");
        b.setBounds(0, 4, 190, 40);
        b.setFocusPainted(false);
        b.setBorderPainted(false);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);
        
        b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            {
                
                p2.setVisible(true);
                
                
            }
        });
        
        
        
        Container c=getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.gray);
        setBounds(170, 100, 1250, 500);
        
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        new JFrameBackground();
        

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Why is the GUI so wide? Are other components being added to this GUI? Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work better.

- I fixed radiobutton and checkbox positions.
- I used different references for checkbox and radiobutton objects (r1, r2, chk1, chk2, chk3)
- I added a buttongroup for radiobuttons.

  ```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
   import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
   import javax.swing.JComboBox;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
   import javax.swing.JTextField;

   import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

   public class JFrameBackground extends JFrame implements ActionListener
   {


       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


       JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
       JTextField t1;
       JButton b1;
       JRadioButton r1, r2;
       JComboBox com1;
       JCheckBox chk1, chk2, chk3;

       JPanel p2;
       JButton b;



       public JFrameBackground() 
       {

           p2=new JPanel();
           p2.setLayout(null);
           p2.setBounds(250, 0, 400, 400);
           add(p2);


           l1 = new JLabel("Name:");
           l1.setBounds(100,10,70,30);
           p2.add(l1);

           t1 = new JTextField();
           t1.setBounds(100,50,70,30);
           p2.add(t1);

           l2 = new JLabel("Gender:");
           l2.setBounds(100,130,70,30);
           p2.add(l2);

           r1 = new JRadioButton("Male");
           r1.setBounds(100,150,70,30);
           p2.add(r1);

           r2 = new JRadioButton("Female");
           r2.setBounds(180,150,70,30);
           p2.add(r2);

           ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();    
           bg.add(r1);
           bg.add(r2); 

           l3 = new JLabel("Course:");
           l3.setBounds(100,180,70,30);
           p2.add(l3);

           chk1= new JCheckBox("Bca");
           chk1.setBounds(100, 200, 70, 30);
           p2.add(chk1);

           chk2= new JCheckBox("BBA");
           chk2.setBounds(180, 200, 70, 30);
           p2.add(chk2);

           chk3= new JCheckBox("BCOM");
           chk3.setBounds(260, 200, 70, 30);
           p2.add(chk3);

           l4 = new JLabel("Country:");
           l4.setBounds(100,220,70,30);
           p2.add(l4);

           String name[] = {"India","USA","UK","Rus"};

           com1=new JComboBox(name);
           com1.setBounds(100, 250, 70, 30);
           p2.add(com1);

           b1= new JButton("Submit");
           b1.setBounds(140, 300, 90, 30);
           p2.add(b1);




           b =new JButton("Show form");
           b.setBounds(0, 4, 190, 40);
           b.setFocusPainted(false);
           b.setBorderPainted(false);
           b.addActionListener(this);
           getContentPane().add(b);

           b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
           {
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
               {

                   p2.setVisible(true);


               }
           });



           Container c=getContentPane();
           c.setBackground(Color.gray);
           setBounds(170, 100, 1250, 500);

           setLayout(null);
           setVisible(true);
       }


       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {

           new JFrameBackground();


       }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
       {


       }

   }
  ```

Comment: I've made the changes You suggested and now the boxes don't disappear.Thanks.

Comment: (1-)  Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager would make sure components don't overlap. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score -1):

The Components to the left are too large and therefore overlap the checkboxes. Thats why they are not shown correctly. So move the right components like that:

```
 r1.setBounds(170, 150, 70, 30);
 chk1.setBounds(170, 200, 70, 30);              
 chk1.setBounds(240, 200, 70, 30);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Please refrain from trying to help with cross-platform GUIs until you work out why that is such sub-optimal advice. Minus 1.